# How do I configure Windows so that it won't recognize USB as Ethernet?

Tags: windows, networking, usb, ethernet

In light of the increasing ability for people to [steal credentials using a USB Ethernet adapter](http://securityaffairs.co/wordpress/51026/hacking/sniff-credentials-ethernet-adapter.html), I would like to make it so that Windows will not recognize USB devices as Ethernet adapters.

Is there a way that I can do this locally, and on a domain? We are using Windows 7 and up and Server 2012.

Answer (score 0):

You could do that via Group Policy Management tool. Create a new Group Policy Object in Device Installation Restriction category, and list device classes you want to forbid. I believe network adapters are in [USB communication device](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB_communications_device_class) class, but I'm not sure.

[Here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2007.06.grouppolicy.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)'s a detailed guide.